# Reading command prompt output into variables - GVIM and Windows

Tags: vimscript, gvim, microsoft-windows

First off, I'm writing this for my setup at work, which is entirely on Windows. I'd imagine it would be quite a bit easier if I was able to use a proper terminal.

I've written a function in my vimrc that lets me run a syntax checker for the obscure programming language we use here. I'd like to read the output from that syntax checker into a variable in the function, which I can then use to set some linenumber marks or output to a temp buffer (like Syntastic).

I browsed through the helpfile and found redir =>, but it doesn't seem to work like I'd expect it to.

```
" SYNTAX CHECK FOR PROGRESS
" =========================
function! CheckSyntaxCustom()
  if (&ft=='progress')
  redir => progress_output
    :execute '0read !c:\progress\openedge11_3\bin\_progres.exe -1 -b -Mm 16384 -pf c:\progress\openedge11_3\startup.pf -p c:\code\custom\syntax.p -param %:p'
  redir end
  :echom progress_output
  endif
endfunction
```

Seems like I can't manipulate progress_output. Ideally I'd like it to return a string that I can then use with :execute, but right now it just pastes the command prompt output to the line below the cursor. I'm fairly new to vimscript so I could be completely wrong on what redir should be used for. Any advice on how to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim already includes everything you need to achieve what you are looking for, as long as it is properly configured for your environment.

Take a look at the following Vim help pages:

- [`'makeprg'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27)
- [`:make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:make)
- [`'errorformat'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27errorformat%27) (you also need to read [`errorformat`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#errorformat))
- [`quickfix.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix.txt)

You can also look at [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) syntax plugins that include various examples for `'errorformat'`. You can find a tool that you know (or that you have access to) and use those entries as an example for your development. While I don't personally use [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic), do consider creating a Pull Request to have your language included in it.